# Trying to show if two languages are recognizable or not

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I have two languages that I am trying to prove are recognizable or not:

> Let $$L_1 = \{(\langle M\rangle, w) \mid \text{$M$ is a TM that accepts $w$ and doesn't accept $\varepsilon$}\}$$ where TM is short for "Turing
>   Machine", $w$ is a string, and $ε$ is the empty string.
>
> Is $L_1$ recognizable? Prove your answer is correct.

> Let $$L_2 = \{(\langle M\rangle, w) \mid \text{$M$ is a TM that accepts $w$ and rejects $\varepsilon$} \}$$ Is $L_2$ recognizable? Prove your answer
>   is correct.

I've been having trouble with these proofs using mapping reducibility. I know that the language
$$A_\mathrm{TM} = \{\langle M, w \rangle \mid \text{$M$ is a Turing machine that accepts the string $w$}\}$$
is undecidable but recognizable. My approach is to say that
$$L = \{\langle M, \varepsilon\rangle \mid \text{$M$ is a Turing machine that rejects $\varepsilon$} \}$$
is recognizable and, knowing that recognizable languages are closed under intersection, this shows $L$ is also recognizable.

I'm not too sure about the first question, however. Is there a better approach to proving these two languages are recognizable or not?

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Deleting your question after receiving answers is bad style. Don't do that!